# I need to send json request for multiple users using csv file in jmeter

Tags: json, csv

I have a csv file containing user names and password, i need to use that csv file to pass for json request but im getting internal sever error as json cant understand csv files.

please help me what i need to do for passing json request for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the CSV using the `User CSV Reader` and set the inputs to variables, say for example ${Username}, ${Password}. Then, wherever you are creating your JSON use a pre-processor to assign these values where they need to go - for example, if you had a template JSON that you loaded and had a field "username: ", you could set that field equal to the variable ${Username}.